# yootheme UIkit notify not work

Tags: javascript, uikit, notify

I would like to use UIkit notify instead alert of javascript to check if a form login is empty. But with this code it not work.

```
function checkLoginForm()
    {
        var loginname = document.forms["formLogin"]["login"].value;
        if (loginname == null || loginname == "")
        {
            UIkit.notify({
                  message : 'UserName must be filled out',
                  timeout : 5000,
                  status  : 'success'
              });
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Could you help please?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`$.UIkit.notify("Your message text", {status: 'danger'});`